# A small program using C, to find the largest of the four numbers using if, else

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and also "programming". Less than one month so far. I made a small program which prints the largest and smallest integers among the four input numbers. Is there any shortest way using the basic c programming methods?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{   
    int a, b, c, d, y;

    printf("Enter four integers (separate them with spaces): ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    if (a>b && a>c && a>d){
      if (b<c && b<d){
        y = b;
      }
      else if (c<b && c<d){
        y = c;
      }
      else if (d<b && d<c){
        y = d;
      }

      printf("Largest: %d\n", a);
      printf("Smallest: %d", y);
    }
    else if (b>a && b>c && b>d) {
      if (a<c && a<d){
        y = a;
      }
      else if(c<a && c<d){
        y = c;
      }
      else if(d<a && d<c){
        y = d;
      }

      printf("Largest: %d\n", b);
      printf("Smallest: %d", y);
    }
    else if (c>a && c>b && c>d)
    {
      if (a<b && a<d){
        y = a;
      }
      else if(b<a && b<d){
        y = b;
      }
      else if(d<a && d<b){
        y = d;
      }

      printf("Largest: %d\n", c);
      printf("Smallest: %d", y);
    }
    else if (d>a && d>b && d>c) {
      if (a<b && a<c){
        y = a;
      }
    else if(b<a && b<c){
      y = b;
    }
    else if(c<a && c<b){
      y = c;
    }

    printf("Largest: %d\n", d);
    printf("Smallest: %d", y);
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Look into arrays, and for loops. Try to implement this with 20 elements instead of 4, and you'll see that your solution doesn't scale.

Comment: If this code is working then the question probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: anyway good job with logical thinking, it is important first step :)

Comment: the code does not cleanly compile.  when using a OS, the return type from main() is always `int`.    When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ( besides those parameters, I also use: `-Wconversion -std=c99` )

Comment: for readability and understandability by us humans, please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: @user3629249 `-pedantic` "at a minimum"? That's a bit extreme.  I always suggest `-Wall -Werror` at a minimum - it forces the user to fix real problems that will almost certainly cause problems. In my experience, going from `-Wextra` to `pedantic` rarely brings out actual bugs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about working code, seeking advice for improvement are better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart,yes, `-pedantic` because the coder, in general, should not be using compiler specific extensions to the language.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the world of programming. You will love it here :)

In logical thinking you should always try to think of a general solution that can scale up easily.

A more general approach to the maximum value problem is to arbitrarily set the max value and then using a loop compare will all other values.

place the numbers in an array.

```
int array[] = {a,b,c,d};
```

set the max and min value arbitrarily to the first element of the array

```
int max = array[0];
int min = array[0];
```

Run the loop to the length of the array and compare each element with the max. If its greater than the max value, update the max value. Likewise compare each element with the min value and if its smaller than the min value, update the min value.

```
int length = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];
for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
    {
       if(array[n]>max)
       {
        max = array[i];
       }
       if(array[n]<min)
       {
        min = array[i];
       }
    }
printf("Maximum Number:\t%d\n",max);
printf("Minimum Number:\t%d\n",min);
```

With this approach you can easily scale up to large number of inputs and its fairly simple.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any shortest way using the basic c programming methods?

Based on your Question a `for loop` will do the job:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void){
    int array[] = {1,6,15,9};
    int length = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];
    int big, small;

    big=small=array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(array[i]>big){
            big=array[i];
        }

        if(array[i]<small){
            small=array[i];
        }
    }

    printf("The biggest Number is:\t%d\n",big);
    printf("The smallest Number is:\t%d\n",small);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The biggest Number is:  15
The smalles Number is:  1
```

Any way i think this is a [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Question and not SO.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward approach is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{   
    int a, b, c, d;
    int largest, smallest;

    printf( "Enter four integers (separate them with spaces): " );
    scanf( "%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d );


    largest = smallest = a;

    if ( largest < b )
    {
        largest = b;
    }
    else if ( b < smallest )
    {
        smallest = b;
    }
    if ( largest < c )
    {
        largest = c;
    }
    else if ( c < smallest )
    {
        smallest = c;
    }
    if ( largest < d )
    {
        largest = d;
    }
    else if ( d < smallest )
    {
        smallest = d;
    }

    printf( "\nLargest: %d\n", largest );
    printf( "Smallest: %d", smallest );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter for example

```
3 2 1 4
```

then output will be

```
Enter four integers (separate them with spaces): 3 2 1 4

Largest: 4
Smallest: 1
```

Another approach is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{   
    int a, b, c, d;

    printf( "Enter four integers (separate them with spaces): " );
    scanf( "%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d );

    if ( !( a < b || a < c || a < d ) )
    {        
        printf( "\nLargest: %d\n", a );
    }        
    else if ( !( b < c || b < d ) )
    {        
        printf( "\nLargest: %d\n", b );
    }        
    else if ( !( c < d ) )
    {        
        printf( "\nLargest: %d\n", c );
    }        
    else 
    {        
        printf( "\nLargest: %d\n", d );
    }        

    if ( !( b < a || c < a || d < a ) )
    {        
        printf( "Smallest: %d", a );
    }        
    else if ( !( c < b || d < b ) )
    {        
        printf( "Smallest: %d", b );
    }        
    else if ( !( d < c ) )
    {        
        printf( "Smallest: %d", c );
    }        
    else 
    {        
        printf( "Smallest: %d", d );
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be the same for the same input.

if to use an array of integers then you can write a general function like this

```
struct minmax
{
    int *min;
    int *max;
}

struct minmax minmax_element( int *a, size_t n )
{
    struct minmax m = { a, a };

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] < *m.min ) m.min = a + i;
        else if ( *m.max < a[i] ) m.max = a + i;
    }

    return m;
}
```

This function can work even for empty sequences. It returns a structure of pointers to the largest and smallest elements in an array.

As for ypur approach then in general it is incorrect. It does not take into account that some (or even all) numbers can be equal each other.

Also according to the C Standard function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach with functions is more dynamic, reusable and readable:

```
int max(int* arr ,int n) {

    if (n < 0)
        return 0;

    int ans = arr[0];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        if (arr[i]>ans) {
            ans = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return ans;
}

int min(int* arr ,int n) {

    if (n < 0)
        return 0;

    int ans = arr[0];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        if (arr[i]<ans) {
            ans = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;

    printf("Enter four integers (separate them with spaces): ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    int arr[] = {a, b, c, d};
    printf("Largest: %d\n", max(arr, 4));
    printf("Smallest: %d", min(arr, 4));

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You can do all that using only one Function where pointers are involved [Like this](http://ideone.com/Z3dEQs).

Answer (score 0):

the following code incorporates error checking and is about as short/simple an implementation of the functionality without getting into code that will be difficult for the new programmer to understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <limits.h> // INT_MAX, INT_MIN

#define MAX_INPUTS (4)

int main( void )
{
    // declare array of MAX_INPUTS integers
    int myInputs[ MAX_INPUTS];

    // for flexibility, the printf() and scanf() could be in a loop
    // so most any number (defined in MAX_INPUTS) could be used
    // with out changing anything but the #define statement
    printf("Enter four integers (separate them with spaces): ");
    if( 4 != scanf("%d %d %d %d", &myInputs[0], &myInputs[1], &myInputs[2], &myInputs[3]) )
    { // then scanf failed
        // output error message, including the system error message to stderr
        perror( "scanf for 4 inputs failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    int minValue = INT_MAX;
    int maxValue = INT_MIN;

    for( size_t i=0; i< MAX_INPUTS; i++ )
    {
        if( myInputs[i] > maxValue) maxValue = myInputs[i];
        if( myInputs[i] < minValue) minValue = myInputs[i];
    }

      printf("Largest: %d\n", maxValue);
      printf("Smallest: %d\n", minValue);

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```